# How to expand $|(1-H(f))|^2$, $H(f)$ is complex.

Tags: complex-numbers

This problem might be simple.

How to expand $|(1-H(f))|^2$? I just see one answer in the following:

[image]

(A typo: $S_X(f)$ should be outside the $\{\}$).

My answer is $1+|H(f)|^2 + 2|H(f)|$.

However, "$2\text{Re}[H(f)]\neq2|H(f)|$". (One is the lenght of the vector, the other is the length of the projection onto the real line).

How to expand $|(1-H(f))|^2$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: For complex numbers, $a.a^* = |a|^2$. where $a^*$ is the complex conjugate of $a$.

The error in your step is that you took
$$|1-H(f)|^2 = |1-H(f)||1-H(f)| = (1+|H(f)|)(1+|H(f)|)$$

The last equality is wrong and is in fact a $\le$ by triangle inequality.